# Cannot add new content types to a manually added pagelibrary

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, libraries

I have a page library by default on my subpage, but now I want to add more. So I go to the different apps via the menu item "Add App" and add a page library. By default it has such an old ugly homepage and only the old wiki-page to choose from.

[image: only wiki-page]

I want to add pages of the new kind of pages to this page library, like in the standard library.

[image: create new websitesite]

So I thought I'd take a look at the library settings. Unfortunately I had to find out that I can add new content types to the standard page library.

[image: here I can add new content-types]

In the manually added page library this configuration option is missing.

[image: here I can't]

How do I get it right that I can also add/store the new page in this library?

Comment: You to set "AllowContentType Management" to "Yes" in advanced setting, is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you create this page library using Wiki Page Library template in the "Add an app" page?

If so, it’s the default behavior, we can only create wiki page in the Wiki Page library and there is no option to add new content type.

You can get more information about this library template: [Create and edit a wiki](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-edit-a-wiki-dc64f9c2-d1a2-44b5-ac59-b9d535551a32)

It’s not supported to create custom Pages library as OOB Pages library in SharePoint Online.